# Multiple Nvidia Packages Installed

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm having trouble loading my NVIDIA drivers on different kernels.  I think I narrowed it down towards my driver installation. I have the newest 450 driver installed, but there are remnants of the old 440 driver, I can't figure out how to uninstall them and reinstall my 450 drivers.

`dpkg -l | grep nvidia`

```
ii  libnvidia-common-450                       450.57-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.2                     all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
rc  libnvidia-compute-440:amd64                440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-450:amd64                450.57-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.2                     amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-450:i386                 450.57-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.2                     i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-450:amd64                 450.57-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.2                     amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-450:i386                  450.57-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.2                     i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-450:amd64                 450.57-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.2                     amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-450:i386                  450.57-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.2                     i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-450:amd64                  450.57-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.2                     amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-450:amd64                   450.57-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.2                     amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-450:i386                    450.57-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.2                     i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-450:amd64                     450.57-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.2                     amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-450:i386                      450.57-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.2                     i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-450:amd64                   450.57-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.2                     amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-450:i386                    450.57-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.2                     i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  screen-resolution-extra                    0.18build1                                    all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450              450.57-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.2                     amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

The problem seems to be "rc  libnvidia-compute-440:amd64                440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package"

Anyone have any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: The `libnvidia-compute-440` is not installed. Instead of asking this I suggest to describe what is your real problem "with different kernels:" See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out myself. (thanks pilot6)

`sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'`

`sudo apt-get --purge remove libnvidia-compute-440`

Then reinstalled the NVIDIA driver.  Now my driver works on the different versions of kernels I have installed.  Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.